# Django is not rendering data when using ajax

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I have a simple code in my template.html:

```
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="buttonId" value="Show Data">  
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#buttonId').click(function() {    
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token,
                    click: true
                },
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response) // it is a HTML, not my data
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    {{results}}
```

And in my views.py:

```
    if request.POST.get('click', False):
        ... #here I get finalresults
        return render(request, 'template.html', context={
            'results': finalresults
        })
```

When I push the Button, the script runs. So I know that after pushing the button, finalresults has content, but this content does not arrive to the HTML template.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> console.log(response) // it is a HTML, not my data

**You are getting HTML because you are rendering the whole template.**

I think you just want to return `results`. In this case, just change:

```
return render(request, 'template.html', context={
    'results': finalresults,
})
```

To:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
...
...
return JsonResponse(
    {'results': finalresults},
)
```